# Download multiple files simultaneously with PHP - Forking, Sockets

Tags: php, file, download, fork

I'm using the following code to manage downloads from my site (the files are behind a captcha): http://www.richnetapps.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/

Trouble is, when a file is being downloaded, it locks the rest of the site, and it's not possible to download another file simultaneously. ('Locks' as in trying to go to, say, the homepage when a download is in progress results in a long wait. The homepage appears only when the download is finished or cancelled. This is a problem because some of the files are several hundred MB).

I'd like two things to happen: 1- To be able to browse the site while a file is being downloaded, and 2- to be able to download another file (or two, or three, or ten...) simultaneously.

My gut feeling is I need to fork the process, create a new one, or open another socket. But I'm way out of my depth, and even if this was the right approach, I don't know how to do it. Any ideas guys?

Many thanks in advance....

**EDIT----
I found it! I added session_write_close() right before setting the headers in the download script. Apparently this behaviour is due to PHP session handling - further info here: [php simultaneous file downloads from the same browser and same php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797807/php-simultaneous-file-downloads-from-the-same-browser-and-same-php-script?rq=1) (I searched and searched before asking, but obviously missed this post).
Many thanks....**

Comment: You absolutely do not need to implement this in PHP, nor should you attempt to do so. Sockets are opened and parallel requests are juggled **far** below the level of PHP. Apache (or whichever server you're using) will do this for you. If your site is only allowing one request at a time, your server software needs to be properly configured.

Comment: The behavior you are experiencing sounds an awful lot like the *normal* exclusive lock that PHP sets on the user session.  While the example code doesn't use sessions, perhaps you've modified it to do so?

Comment: Charles - I did! for the captcha verification. I found the solution, please see my edit above. Thanks for taking the time to reply guys.

Answer (score 0):

A Content Delivery Network (CDN) will both offload from your server allowing your server to process homepage (or other) page requests, and allow many, many simultaneous downloads. It should be cheaper for bandwidth and perhaps faster for most users as well.

The key will be to configure to protect the files only after your Captcha, instead of being freely available like most CDN setups.